# Cypress: How to test that content is *not* accessible (clickable etc) because of overlay?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I have implemented a loading indicator in Angular that looks like this:

```
<div cdkTrapFocus class="activity-indicator-container">
  <div class="content-container">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div [ngStyle]="{visibility: showLoader ? 'visible': 'hidden'}" class="indicator-overlay">
      <div class="loading-indicator">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `indicator-overlay` is styled like that:

```
  .indicator-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
}
```

When the indicator is displayed, the content is greyed out by a semi-transparent div.

Running `cy.contains('text in content').should('not.be.visible')` fails when the overlay is displayed.

So is there a way to test in Cypress that the text is actually *not accessible* (selectable, clickable etc)?

Comment: There is a Chai-jquery assertion which checks whether element is hidden or not. Can you try that `cy.get('locator').then(($el) => {expect($el).to.be.hidden})` or you can check whether the element exists or not `cy.get('locator').should('not.exist')`. You can refer more such assertions here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai

Comment: From what I understand, hidden refers to "display: none" and existing to be present in the DOM which both will not work since the element is both in the DOM and is visible.

Comment: Ya that makes sense. One other way I can think of is to check the presence of class .indicator-overlay with something like .should(‘have.class’, ‘indicator-overlay’)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try/catch block. It sounds like you are testing that the overlay is trapping any click events, more than you are testing that the elements are not clickable (since you aren't changing the elements themselves)

You could do something like this

```
displayLoadingOverlay();
try{
  // this should fail, since the overlay will be blocking it
  element.click();
} catch(error){
  expect(error).to.contain(message);
}
```

this test ensures that if you try to click on the element (repeat for as many elements as you would like) an error should be thrown since the element is not clickable by Cypress. If no error is thrown, you can assume the click event worked.

Comment: Because of the very expressive, declarative and asynchronous way Cypress works, I was not aware of using things like try...catch. Honestly, this looks not very elegantly but it could work. I was hoping for something more like `.should('not.be.clickable')` or `.should('not.be.reachable')`.